# JavaScript round number to first two digits?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to round a number up to the first two digits.

```
14300 -> 15000
1430  -> 1500
143   -> 150
14    -> 14
```

I have figured out this much:

```
var n = 14300;
n = parseFloat(Math.ceil(n).toPrecision(2));
console.log(n);
```

It returns 14000, but I want to round it up. Math.ceil only works to the next integer.
http://jsfiddle.net/cruTY/

Note: I know I can divide `n` to make it a decimal, but I want this function to work for all numbers without having to manually insert `/1000` or `/1000000`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
var n = 14300;
if (String(n).length > 2) {
    var d = Math.pow(10, String(n).length-2);
    n = Math.ceil(n/d)*d;
}
console.log(n);
```

What's your requirement if `String(n).length < 2`?

Alternately,

```js
var n = 143;
var l = String(n).length;
if (l > 2) {
  var p = Number(String(n).slice(0, 3)) / 10;
  n = Math.ceil(p) + '';
  while (n.length < l) {
    n += '0';
  }
  n = Number(n);
}
console.log(n);
```

Comment: Doesn't round up like the OP wants and only ends up with two digits.  Your example ends up with 14, not 15000.

Comment: sorry, I was afk, it seems to work, thanks! To any viewers, is this the right way to do it?

Comment: To fix the < 10 issue use: `n>10? Math.ceil(n/d) * d : Math.ceil(n);`

Answer (score 2):

I could only think of this

```
var n = 14300;
var N = n + "";
console.log(N.length > 2 ? (parseInt(N.substr(0, 2)) + 1) * (Math.pow(10, N.length - 2)) : n);
```

**Output**

```
15000
```

Answer (score 1):

This one doesn’t need special handling for n < 10:

```
function roundUpToPrecision(n, d) {
    var round = n.toPrecision(d);

    if(round === n.toString()) {
        return n;
    }

    return +(n + 0.5 * Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log(n) * Math.LOG10E) - 1)).toPrecision(d);
}
```

Comment: +1 this is so complicated, but it works for decimals too! :o. I also this you need to parseFloat() the return.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is more universal than other ones, because you can change the values around easily. This function will `ceil` to **any index** of the number you need. If its to third or second, just change the `dig` to corresponding number:

```js
function ceil(num, ind){
    let str = Math.floor(num)+"",
        arr = new Array(str.length).fill("0");
        arr[ind - 1] = "1";
    let divider = arr.join("");
  
    return Math.ceil(num/divider) * divider;
}

let number = 14300, //which number to be ceiled
    dig = 2; //to which index we ceil

document.body.textContent = ceil( number, dig );
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works with numbers.

```
function roundValue(value) {
    const valueAbs = Math.abs(value);
    const exponent = Math.round(Math.log10(valueAbs)) - 1;
    const power = Math.pow(10, exponent);
    return Math.ceil(valueAbs / power) * power;
}
```